# Tell phpunit to call public instead of private

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

My Question is. I have a class i want to test (myClass). In myClass there is a function wich calls a private function thats also in the myClass.

I know i can't test private functions. Is it possible to tell phpunit to call another function instead of the private?

**Example**

`$this->testclass` is now the class i want to test

```
$this->testclass = new \stdClass();
$this->testclass->mock = $this->getMockBuilder('myClass')->getMock();
```

Outside my testcase i have created a fake class.

```
$this->mockextended = new \stdClass();
$this->mockextended->mock = new MOCKEXTENDEDCLASSES();
```

in the `$this->mockextended` i have a public function.

the function i want to test

```
public function TestMe(){
$this->somePrivateFunctioniHate(); <==== this is the pain in my ass
}
```

and the private function

```
private function somePrivateFunctioniHate(){
   //come code
    }
```

What i want to do is. the function TestMe is calling a private function. 
Is it possible to tell phpunit to override the private function and call another function thats inside `$this->mockextended;`
I have tried it like this.

```
$this->testclass->somePrivateFunctioniHate() = $this->mockextended->theWholeNewPrivateFunction()
```

only this gives me a nice error. I did this before and it worked. Called it like this

**EDIT**
For people who don't understand my question. 
I have another function that calls another class. I din't want to have another class in my test so i created a fake Class outside my testcase. Inserted the same functions as the class the function wants to include. Did it like this

```
  $this->testclass->chunks = new \stdClass();
    //MOCKchunckTpl is the fake class outside my testcase
            $this->testclass->chunks->config = new MOCKchunkTpl();
```

This works. Whenever a function wants to call `$this->testclass->chunks->config->Somefunction();` it will be redirected to my fake class.

**BUT** when i try to do the same with a function thats calling a private function. Like `$this->testclass->somePrivateFunctioniHate() = $this->mockextended->theWholeNewPrivateFunction()` it gives a nice error

```
Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in
```

Comment: Why do you always instantiate a `new \stdClass()` before filling the same variable with your mock?

Comment: I want it to use it like $object->otherobject->anotherobject->thisonetoo......

Comment: But you are overwriting the variable immediately. In those two cases the `stdClass` gets lost and the instantiation is pointless.

Comment: Well. maybe it will. But thats not the question i asked

Comment: Which is why I mentioned this in the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No, there isn't. There is no way for PHPUnit to manipulate private methods.

Mocks are for faking the behavior of classes, which depend on the class you want to test. If you need to overwrite a private method, there is something wrong in your architecture. Private methods should be tested by simple testing the public methods in which they are used. If you need to test it separately, declare it public.

**EDIT:** Here is an example how you'd test a simple code using a private method or putting this private method in another class:

**1. Private method**

```
class MyClass {

    public function myMethod() {
        return $this->myPrivateMethod();
    }

    private function myPrivateMethod() {
        return 2;
    }

}
```

And the test class:

```
class MyClassTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testMyMethod() {
        $myClass = new MyClass();
        // don't mind the private method, just test if the public method is working
        $this->assertEquals(2, $myClass->myMethod());
    }

}
```

**1. Second class**

```
class MyClass {

    public $dependentClass;

    public function myMethod() {
        return $this->dependentClass->dependentMethod();
    }

}
```

And the dependent class:

```
class DependentClass {

    public function dependentMethod() {
        return 38943;
    }

}
```

Testing `MyClass` with the `DependentClass`:

```
class MyClassTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testMyMethod() {
        $dependentMock = $this->getMockBuilder("DependentClass")->getMock();
        $dependentMock->expects($this->any())
            ->method("dependentMethod")
            ->willReturn($this->returnValue(2));

        $myClass = new MyClass();
        $myClass->dependentClass = $dependentMock;

        $this->assertEquals(2, $myClass->myMethod());
    }
```

Although we defined a whole other return in `DependentClass`, the test will still pass, because we mocked it and are able to define every behavior we'd expect `DependentClass` to have.

But to cleanly test the project, we need to define another test for `DependentClass` as well to test, if this class is working. This test should fail if it is not working anymore, not the test for `MyClass`.

Comment: Well. And why is it working with the last example i gave in my question?
$this->testclass->mock->config = new someClass(); //<== works like a charm

Comment: In this case, you are not using the private method of the class you want to test, but make your class dependent on another one. This is a classic use case for mock objects. So usually you won't create a fake class but get a mock object of the class you inject and call its methods.